# There isn't enough memory to perform this operation

Tags: out-of-memory, ms-access-2010, subreport, print-preview

I am making an automated report that gets sent to some pretty important people.

This is one report with 7 subreports, and there are several subreports in those 7 subreports. to get an idea of how big the report is:

1. first subreport has 2 subreports
2. second subreport has 13 subreports
3. third subreport has 2 subreports
4. fourth subreport has 2 subreports
5. fifth subreport has 4 subreports
6. sixth subreport has 6 subreports
7. seventh subreport has 3 subreports

in the seventh subreport, they have multiple subreports as well.

1. first subreport within the seventh one has 17 subreports
2. second subreport within the seventh one has a subreport which is a table       that pulls data to compare data
3. first subreport within the seventh one has 17 subreports

Another issue im having is that when i view the report in print preview it's only supposed to make 2 pages but instead makes 35 pages and on every other page has that subreport which references to data in the table im looking at within the report.

The main issue however is that when i go to print the fist two pages of the report to observe how the data looks on paper i get the message:

[There isn't enough memory to perform this operation. Close unneeded programs and try the operation again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOoGX.jpg) (couldn't post a picture of the image)
Then after click OK on the error message 7 times it then says:
[System resource exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEwyZ.jpg)

I've tried compacting/repairing the database, copying the queries and subreports to another database to see if that would fix it, and now i am at a loss of what to do. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use a paging file for virtual memory? This could be constraining amount of memory needed to run the process.

Comment: Just checked and paging file isn't set up for virtual memory.

Comment: How much memory is consumed by the application when it hits this point?

Comment: When it hits the error point Access only uses about 53-54 MBs of RAM. then after the memory errors finish Access crashes and closes

Comment: Which version of Access? 2013 or 2016?

Comment: This version is 2010

Comment: You need to simplify or split your report. Do you really need *that* many subreports? I can't imagine there isn't a better way to present the data.

Comment: I'm experimenting with presenting the data in a better way. But as of now, that is the way I know of right now that I can present the data. I can get it as far as to view the data in Print Preview mode, I just can't print the report because there is too much on there.

Comment: Just an update on this I was able to get my report working. I created some macros that build tables and I put those tables into my report and it's displayed how i want it to be.